# Are there decision problems outside of NP?

Tags: computability, time-complexity

Consider any problem in NP-hard, then it has a polynomial reduction from a problem in NP in polynomial time. Though, it isn't clear by this definition whether there are decision problems in NP-hard that are not in NP.

Are there any known ones?

Comment: Have you checked the definition of [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) and [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) at wikipedia?

Comment: I did read it lightly, it is indeed answered there as I see now but I missed it somehow. anyway I think It's good it's here as well, as I think it's quite an important fact and it isn't here and isn't very emphasized in Wikipedia

Comment: I'm sure we have several duplicates of this. Anyone got one handy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nondeterministic [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) shows that, e.g., $\mathrm{NP}\subsetneq\mathrm{NEXP}$, so any $\mathrm{NEXP}$-complete problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard but not in $\mathrm{NP}$.  For a more extreme example, the halting problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard but not in $\mathrm{NP}$.